# Centering a variable-width div positioned with left: x%

Tags: html, css

How can I center a variable-width div while positioning it a percentage along a rule?

In the first image below, the `105.4` has `left: 12%`. The problem is that that 12% applies to the leftmost edge of it, rather than the middle.

How can I position it, say 12% along, but have its center at 12%, rather than its edge, like in the second image below?

[image]

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKXyQ/) for the code. I can't use Javascript, and I can't fix the width of the `105.4` div.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `div.y` in a new `div.c` which has `width: 24%;` and `text-align: center;` set. `24%` is `12% * 2`

<kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKXyQ/4/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="c" style="width:24%;text-align:center;">
        <div class="y">105.4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b" style="width:12%;margin-right:auto;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @avrahamcool - the fiddle is for demo/testing purposes? It's just to show that it would work when the `12%` is changed to another number, which OP's "How can I position it, say 12% along," implies, the HTML in the answer provides the answer based on the `12%` question.

Comment: but still, your solution make him apply 2 sizes to accomplish the desired effect. it can be done with one.

Comment: @avrahamcool - Yes, you're right, that's an even simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest solution.
You only need to specify one width. (no need to touch the margin, or left values)

Check out this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/KKXyQ/9/) [multiple width to demonstrate]

This is the **HTML** (add another wrapper, and moved your `y`)

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b" style="width:12%;">
            <div class="c"><div class="y">105.4</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:** (most of it is copied from you)

```
.x {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.y {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
.a {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #007d61;
}
.b
{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f00000;
    position:relative;
}
.c
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 100%;
}
body {
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you do the 12% to draw red line. It will end at the 12 %. So When you add half of it which is 6%. I believe it will work.

```
<div class="y" style="left:6%;">105.4</div>
```

**Updated**

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKXyQ/6/)

Comment: 1. you're demo don't show your solution. 2. your solution don't work as expected

Comment: avrahamcool: I have updated the fiddle. hope this will what you want

Comment: I'm not the OP lol.. Your solution don't work. try with `50%` and `25%` and you'll see.